# Where to install windows apps requiring write permissions to their directory

Tags: windows, installation, file-permissions

On Windows, i need to install several applications that don't use AppData but instead store their configuration files in their own root directory, therefore they need write permissions to it.

Of course i could just put it into Program Files and then run it everytime with Administrator privileges, but this is not only annoying, it's also not the best security practice.

So where does one put such programs in Windows (optimally so that they are available to all users) ?

Comment: Have you tried running the installers as administrator? Alternatively, if you can't define the data directories during installation, then from an administrator shell create the directories in advance (or make links to more appropriate places, such as `AppData` subdirectories).

Comment: @AFH Create which directories in advance?

Comment: Also, some of them don't even have installers, they just come in a zip.

Comment: 1. The directories that can't be created during installation. 2. Run the unzip program as administrator.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. The problem isn't that directories can't be created, but WHERE to unzip the program. If you unzip it to Program Files, it will not be able to save its data files as it doesn't have write permissions there, and running it always as admin is nonsense.

Comment: I don't fully understand all the implications of your question, but I have several dozen applications that don't require installation, and I created a `C:\Utils` directory with full permissions to everyone, where I unzip all such utilities, each in its own subdirectory. I also make extensive use of [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/), and these all go into `C:\PortApps`, with similar permissions.

Comment: Allright, so you suggest creating another directory next to standard Program Files and put all such programs there? Can you make it an answer please?

Comment: Or you can right-click on a folder in *Program Files* or *Program Files (x86)* in which you've installed the application, select *Properties*, and in the *Security* tab change permissions so that the application  has full control. *Caveat:* this potentially gives the application privileges to cause damage... if by nothing else, then by filling up the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` are the best places, you can change the permissions to allow write access, even if it is in Program Files.

If you have administrator privileges (which I assume you do from your question), you can 
extract the program in a folder you can write to (like your `Desktop`, Home folder, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc). Then as administrator move/copy the folder into `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` and change the permissions of the extracted folder to allow write access for all users (or whom ever needs to run the file). This way, the program is in a place where everyone can access it and doesn't need to be ran as Administrator.

After moving/copying the file, you can change it's permissions by right clicking it, clicking properties then security, then edit. You might need to put in administrator credentials.

[image]

Alternatively, and possibly more secure, you can only change the permissions of the exact log files or log file folder, while keeping the main folder permissions untouched, reckon that is the only thing that the program is writing to. It can be done in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend what I do, which is to create a root directory, such as `%SystemDrive%\Utils` or `%SystemDrive\Programs` (you will need an administrator shell to do this), and install each application into separate subdirectories under that.

If you need shortcuts to the applications, go in Explorer to each application's directory (eg `%SystemDrive%\Utils\AppDir`), then right-click on the application name (eg `%SystemDrive%\Utils\AppDir\AppName.exe`) and select **Copy**. Now go to the shortcut directory where you want the shortcuts (eg Desktop), right click and select **Paste shortcut**.

It's worth looking at [PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/) to see if any of your software is available there. This uses a similar structure, with all the software in individual subdirectories in single master directory (which can be the same one as you created above). The advantage of PortableApps is that they are automatically updated and come with a launcher which is also automatically maintained.

In either case, you can copy the single master directory to any other machine you want, or run from an external drive.